# Is there any way by which the data from the disabled field in the html form is not shown in the downloaded txt file?

Tags: javascript, html

While creating an html form i disabled a field according to the input from the previous dropdown field 'Protocol Type'. Now I am downloading the form data in a text file. All i want is file to have data form the fields which are enabled and the disabled field should not appear in the text file.

For instance I have three fields 'Protocol' and 'iSCSI IPs'. The logic is if Protocol=='iSCSI' then 'iSCSI IPs' is enabled and I am entering text there. But in the case when Protocol is not iSCSI then 'iSCSI IPs' field is diabled, in this scenario i dont need the downloaded data to have 'iSCSI IPs' field in it (or in my case, in the downloaded text file). Entering the entire code here as was not able to reproduce the issue with the minimal code block. Thanks

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 const extra = {};
  
 const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
 const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
 const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
 const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
 const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
 const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
 const oiSCSI = document.querySelector('select[name="iSCSIip"]');
 const oTmp = document.querySelector('template');
  
  //Validating the input data and handling the changes made by the user
 const changehandler = function(e) {
   let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
   else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
   }
  
 if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
  let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
  oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling)
   } else {
   if (document.getElementById('extra')) {
   fieldset = document.getElementById('extra')
     fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
   }
    }
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
  else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }
  
//Enabling the protocol dropdown only if the controller is RAID
 if (this.name == 'controller') {
  if (this.value == 'RAID') oProto.disabled = false
 else oProto.disabled = true
   }
   

 if (this.name == 'protocol') {
  if (this.value == 'iSCSI') oiSCSI.disabled = false
 else oiSCSI.disabled = true
   }
 }
  
  
 const dialog = function(msg) {
   alert(msg);
   return false;
 }
  
 const savehandler = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let valid = true

 /*
 if( oForm.test.value =='' || oForm.controller.value =='' || oForm.ip.value  == '' || oForm.chassis.value == '' || oForm.lo.value == '' || oForm.ro.value == ''){
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        return;
  }
 else if(oForm.extra_ip1.value == '' || oForm.extra_ip.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip1.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip1.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip.value == '' ){
  alert("Please fill all the additonal required fields!");
        return;
 }
  
 const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
 if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
  return dialog('Invalid IP Address');
   }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_IP Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip.value)== false){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Netmask Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Gateway Address');
 }  
 */
 //Creating the data elements to be cpatured in the downloaded yaml file 
 let data = {
  " PDU:": {
    "PDU_IP":['     PDU_IP',' '+oForm.ip.value," #PDU IP",' '+'\n'],
    "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",' '+'\n'],
    "PDU_RIGHT":['     PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", ' '+'\n']
  },
  
  " Controller: # Controller settings \n": {   
   //'Controller Type': oForm.controller.value,
   //'Protocol Type': oForm.protocol.value,
   //'Chasis Inputs': oForm.chassis.value,
   'Controller_ID#1': [" -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD",'','',''+'\n'],
   "iSCSI_IPs_A":['      iSCSI_IPs',' '+[oForm.iSCSIip1.value],"#iSCSI_IPs",''+'\n'],
   "HBA_Ports_A":["      HBA_Ports",oForm.hba_ports1.value,'  # SAS/Fiber Channel ',''+'\n'],
   "Netmask IP_A":["      MC_IP",' '+oForm.extra_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
   "MC_Netmask_A": ["      MC_Netmask",' '+oForm.netmask_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
   'MC_Gateway_A':['      MC_Gateway',' '+oForm.gateway_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
   'MC_A': ['      MC',' '+oForm.rbod_mc1.value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
   'SC_A':['      SC',' '+oForm.rbod_sc1.value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
   'FU_A':['      FU',' '+oForm.rbod_fu1.value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
   'EC_A':["      EC",' '+oForm.rbod_ec1.value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
   'Controller_ID#3': ["      ID",' '+oForm.Controller_ID1.value," #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'], 
   'Controller_ID#2': ["     -  # Controller B for RBOD/EBOD",'','','',''+'\n'],
   "iSCSI_IPs_B":['      iSCSI_IPs', ' '+[oForm.iSCSIip2.value],"#iSCSI_IPs",''+'\n'],
   "HBA_Ports_B":["      HBA_Ports",' '+oForm.hba_ports.value,'  # SAS/Fiber Channel ',''+'\n'],
   "Netmask IP_B":["      Netmask IP",' '+oForm.extra_ip.value,'','  # RBOD MC IP'+'\n'],
   "MC_Netmask_B": ["      MC_Netmask", ' '+oForm.netmask_ip.value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
   'MC_Gateway_B':['      MC_Gateway',' '+oForm.gateway_ip.value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
   'MC_B': ['      MC',' '+oForm.rbod_mc.value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
   'SC_B':['      SC',' '+oForm.rbod_sc.value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
   'FU_B':['      FU',' '+oForm.rbod_fu.value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
   'EC_B':["      EC",' '+oForm.rbod_ec.value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',' '+'\n'],
   'Controller_ID#4': ["      ID", ' '+oForm.Controller_ID.value," #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n']
  },
   };

//Crating the format of the data
    let payload = '';
    payload+= ' -  # UUT 0 configuration'+'\n    -  # Chassis 0 configuration'+String.fromCharCode(10);
    const addToPayload = (object, whitespace) => {

        

    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
        payload += key + '\n';
        const details = object[key];
        for (const key1 of Object.keys(details)){
  const value = details[key1];
        str=value[0];
        com=value[2];
        val=value[1];
  whitespace=value[3];
  var input= JSON.stringify(val);
 
    //output.HBA_Ports = input.HBA_Ports[0].split(',');
    //var array = string.split(',');
    if (Array.isArray(val)){
    payload += whitespace + str + ':' + input + com ;//JSON.stringify(val); 
    console.log(payload)
     }
     else if (val==oForm.hba_ports1.value || val==oForm.hba_ports.value){
     var out= val.split(',');
     payload += whitespace + str + ':' + com + JSON.stringify(out);
     }
     else{payload += whitespace + str + ':' + val + com ;}
        } 
      }
    }
      addToPayload(data, ' ' );

//Converting the data into a yaml file and downloading it on button click
   const blob = new Blob([payload], {
  type: 'text/yaml'
   });
   var file =  oForm.test.value + "_" + oForm.protocol.value + "_UUT_Config" + '.yaml';
  
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = file;
  
   if (window.webkitURL != null) {
  link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
   } else {
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
   }
   link.click();
   }
  
   oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
   oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
   oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
     })

//To Disable the text boxes based on the specific inputs i.e. HBA Ports and iSCSI IPs 
  function EnableDisableTextBox(abc) {
 var selectedValue = abc.options[abc.selectedIndex].value;
 var txt1 = document.getElementById("ip1");
 var txt2 = document.getElementById("ip2");

 var hbadisabled1 = document.getElementById("hba");
 var hbadisabled2 = document.getElementById("hba1");

 txt1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;
 txt2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;

 hbadisabled1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;
 hbadisabled2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;

 if (!txt1.disabled) {
  txt1.focus();
 }
 else if (!txt2.disabled){
  txt2.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled1.disabled) {
  hbadisabled1.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled2.disabled){
  hbadisabled2.focus();
 }

   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
  <!--<h1>User Information </h1>-->
  <style>
   html, html * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-color: teal;
    font-family:calibri;
   }
   html{
      background : radial-gradient(rgba(33, 34, 34, 0.5),rgba(46, 45, 45, 0.5))
   }

   input[type=button],
   input[type=submit]{ 
    padding:1rem;
   }

  
   input[type=number]{
      width: 240px;
   height: 35px;
   font-size: 18px;
   } 

   input[type=text],
   textarea,
   select {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:teal
   }
   fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: initial;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
   }
   #extra{border:2px solid black; background:whitesmoke; border-radius:1rem;box-shadow:0 0 5px black;width:calc(100% - 24px);margin:auto;float:none;clear:both;text-indent: 50px;}
   #extra h6{margin:0}
   #extra style
   .invalid{border:2px solid red!important;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
   
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <template>
   <fieldset id='extra'>
    <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
     <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
     <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips'  disabled="disabled" required />
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1'  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
<br>
<br>
    <label for='Controller_ID2'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller_ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
   <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
   <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
   <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
   <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
   <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
   <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
   <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
   <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
   <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
    
   </fieldset>
  </template>
  
  
  
  <form name='myForm' method='POST' >
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
    <select name='controller' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD'>JBOD
     <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
    <select name='test' required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
     <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='Port Check' >Port Check
     <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic' >FW Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD Generic' >JBOD Generic
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <!-- insert templated additional details here -->
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Protocol Type'><strong> Protocol Type</strong></label>
    <select name='protocol' id="abc" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this);"  required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='IP Address'><strong> IP Address </strong></label>
    <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Left Outlets'><strong>Left Outlets </strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='lo' placeholder='Enter left outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Right Outlets'><strong>Right Outlets</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='ro' placeholder='Enter right outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Chasis Inputs</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='chassis' placeholder='Enter Number of Chasis'  required />
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save data to file' />
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason all the fields are coming in your yaml file is because you are declaring all the values in data. 
To achieve what you want you should check if a form field is **disabled** or not before adding it to the data object.

Also it would be good if you declare these fields in a list and write a generic piece of code which iterates and checks if a field is enabled before adding it to the data object.

I have modified your example to be more generic , you can extend on it to move all the conditional fields you have one by one. As a start it has 'iSCSI_IPs_A', this field is only added if it's enabled in the form (gets added at the bottom).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 const extra = {};
  
 const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
 const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
 const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
 const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
 const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
 const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
 const oiSCSI = document.querySelector('select[name="iSCSIip"]');
 const oTmp = document.querySelector('template');
  
  //Validating the input data and handling the changes made by the user
 const changehandler = function(e) {
   let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
   else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
   }
  
 if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
  let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
  oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling)
   } else {
   if (document.getElementById('extra')) {
   fieldset = document.getElementById('extra')
     fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
   }
    }
  
 if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
  else {
  if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }
  
//Enabling the protocol dropdown only if the controller is RAID
 if (this.name == 'controller') {
  if (this.value == 'RAID') oProto.disabled = false
 else oProto.disabled = true
   }
   

 if (this.name == 'protocol') {
  if (this.value == 'iSCSI') oiSCSI.disabled = false
 else oiSCSI.disabled = true
   }
 }
  
  
 const dialog = function(msg) {
   alert(msg);
   return false;
 }
  
 const savehandler = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let valid = true

 /*
 if( oForm.test.value =='' || oForm.controller.value =='' || oForm.ip.value  == '' || oForm.chassis.value == '' || oForm.lo.value == '' || oForm.ro.value == ''){
        alert("Please fill all the fields!");
        return;
  }
 else if(oForm.extra_ip1.value == '' || oForm.extra_ip.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip1.value == '' || oForm.netmask_ip.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip1.value == '' || oForm.gateway_ip.value == '' ){
  alert("Please fill all the additonal required fields!");
        return;
 }
  
 const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
 if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
  return dialog('Invalid IP Address');
   }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.extra_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_IP Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.netmask_ip.value)== false){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Netmask Address');
 }
 else if (ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip1.value)== false || ipformat.test(oForm.gateway_ip.value)== false ){
  return dialog('Invalid MC_Gateway Address');
 }  
 */
 //Creating the data elements to be cpatured in the downloaded yaml file 
 let data = {
  " PDU:": {
    "PDU_IP":['     PDU_IP',' '+oForm.ip.value," #PDU IP",' '+'\n'],
    "PDU_LEFT":['     PDU_LEFT',[oForm.lo.value]," # left_outlet(s) ",' '+'\n'],
    "PDU_RIGHT":['     PDU_RIGHT',[oForm.ro.value]," # right_outlet(s) ", ' '+'\n']
  },
  
  " Controller: # Controller settings \n": {   
   //'Controller Type': oForm.controller.value,
   //'Protocol Type': oForm.protocol.value,
   //'Chasis Inputs': oForm.chassis.value,
   'Controller_ID#1': [" -  # Controller A for RBOD/EBOD",'','',''+'\n'],
   "HBA_Ports_A":["      HBA_Ports",oForm.hba_ports1.value,'  # SAS/Fiber Channel ',''+'\n'],
   "Netmask IP_A":["      MC_IP",' '+oForm.extra_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC IP',''+'\n'],
   "MC_Netmask_A": ["      MC_Netmask",' '+oForm.netmask_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
   'MC_Gateway_A':['      MC_Gateway',' '+oForm.gateway_ip1.value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
   'MC_A': ['      MC',' '+oForm.rbod_mc1.value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
   'SC_A':['      SC',' '+oForm.rbod_sc1.value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
   'FU_A':['      FU',' '+oForm.rbod_fu1.value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
   'EC_A':["      EC",' '+oForm.rbod_ec1.value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',''+'\n'],
   'Controller_ID#3': ["      ID",' '+oForm.Controller_ID1.value," #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n'], 
   'Controller_ID#2': ["     -  # Controller B for RBOD/EBOD",'','','',''+'\n'],
   "iSCSI_IPs_B":['      iSCSI_IPs', ' '+[oForm.iSCSIip2.value],"#iSCSI_IPs",''+'\n'],
   "HBA_Ports_B":["      HBA_Ports",' '+oForm.hba_ports.value,'  # SAS/Fiber Channel ',''+'\n'],
   "Netmask IP_B":["      Netmask IP",' '+oForm.extra_ip.value,'','  # RBOD MC IP'+'\n'],
   "MC_Netmask_B": ["      MC_Netmask", ' '+oForm.netmask_ip.value,'  # RBOD MC Netmask',''+'\n'],
   'MC_Gateway_B':['      MC_Gateway',' '+oForm.gateway_ip.value,'  # RBOD MC Gateway',''+'\n'],
   'MC_B': ['      MC',' '+oForm.rbod_mc.value,'  # RBOD MC port',''+'\n'],
   'SC_B':['      SC',' '+oForm.rbod_sc.value,'  # RBOD SC port',''+'\n'],
   'FU_B':['      FU',' '+oForm.rbod_fu.value,'  # RBOD FU port',''+'\n'],
   'EC_B':["      EC",' '+oForm.rbod_ec.value,'  # EC port on RBOD or GEM port on JBOD',' '+'\n'],
   'Controller_ID#4': ["      ID", ' '+oForm.Controller_ID.value," #Controller ID, A or B",''+'\n']
  },
   };
    
    const formFields = [
     { key: "iSCSI_IPs_A", 
      display: "iSCSI_IPs",
      name: "iSCSIip1",
     }
    ];
    
    formFields.forEach( function(field) {
      if ( oForm[field.name] && !oForm[field.name].disabled ) {
        data[" Controller: # Controller settings \n"][field.key] = ['      ' + field.display,' '+[oForm[field.name].value],'#' + field.display,''+'\n'];
      }
      
      //"iSCSI_IPs_A":['      iSCSI_IPs',' '+[oForm.iSCSIip1.value],"#iSCSI_IPs",''+'\n'],
    });

//Crating the format of the data
    let payload = '';
    payload+= ' -  # UUT 0 configuration'+'\n    -  # Chassis 0 configuration'+String.fromCharCode(10);
    const addToPayload = (object, whitespace) => {

        

    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
        payload += key + '\n';
        const details = object[key];
        for (const key1 of Object.keys(details)){
  const value = details[key1];
        str=value[0];
        com=value[2];
        val=value[1];
  whitespace=value[3];
  var input= JSON.stringify(val);
 
    //output.HBA_Ports = input.HBA_Ports[0].split(',');
    //var array = string.split(',');
    if (Array.isArray(val)){
    payload += whitespace + str + ':' + input + com ;//JSON.stringify(val); 
    console.log(payload)
     }
     else if (val==oForm.hba_ports1.value || val==oForm.hba_ports.value){
     var out= val.split(',');
     payload += whitespace + str + ':' + com + JSON.stringify(out);
     }
     else{payload += whitespace + str + ':' + val + com ;}
        } 
      }
    }
      addToPayload(data, ' ' );

//Converting the data into a yaml file and downloading it on button click
   const blob = new Blob([payload], {
  type: 'text/yaml'
   });
   var file =  oForm.test.value + "_" + oForm.protocol.value + "_UUT_Config" + '.yaml';
  
   let link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = file;
  
   if (window.webkitURL != null) {
  link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
   } else {
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
   }
   link.click();
   }
  
   oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
   oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
   oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
     })

//To Disable the text boxes based on the specific inputs i.e. HBA Ports and iSCSI IPs 
  function EnableDisableTextBox(abc) {
 var selectedValue = abc.options[abc.selectedIndex].value;
 var txt1 = document.getElementById("ip1");
 var txt2 = document.getElementById("ip2");

 var hbadisabled1 = document.getElementById("hba");
 var hbadisabled2 = document.getElementById("hba1");

 txt1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;
 txt2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? false : true;

 hbadisabled1.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;
 hbadisabled2.disabled = selectedValue == 'iSCSI' ? true : false;

 if (!txt1.disabled) {
  txt1.focus();
 }
 else if (!txt2.disabled){
  txt2.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled1.disabled) {
  hbadisabled1.focus();
 }
 else if (!hbadisabled2.disabled){
  hbadisabled2.focus();
 }

   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
  <!--<h1>User Information </h1>-->
  <style>
   html, html * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-color: teal;
    font-family:calibri;
   }
   html{
      background : radial-gradient(rgba(33, 34, 34, 0.5),rgba(46, 45, 45, 0.5))
   }

   input[type=button],
   input[type=submit]{ 
    padding:1rem;
   }

  
   input[type=number]{
      width: 240px;
   height: 35px;
   font-size: 18px;
   } 

   input[type=text],
   textarea,
   select {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:teal
   }
   fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: initial;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
   }
   #extra{border:2px solid black; background:whitesmoke; border-radius:1rem;box-shadow:0 0 5px black;width:calc(100% - 24px);margin:auto;float:none;clear:both;text-indent: 50px;}
   #extra h6{margin:0}
   #extra style
   .invalid{border:2px solid red!important;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.1)}
   
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
  <template>
   <fieldset id='extra'>
    <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
     <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
     <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips'  disabled="disabled" required />
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1'  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
<br>
<br>
    <label for='Controller_ID2'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller_ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
   <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
   <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
   <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
   <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
   <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
   <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
   <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
   <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
   <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
    
   </fieldset>
  </template>
  
  
  
  <form name='myForm' method='POST' >
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
    <select name='controller' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD'>JBOD
     <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
    <select name='test' required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
     <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
     <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='Port Check' >Port Check
     <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic' >FW Generic
     <option data-extra=true value='JBOD Generic' >JBOD Generic
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <!-- insert templated additional details here -->
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='Protocol Type'><strong> Protocol Type</strong></label>
    <select name='protocol' id="abc" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this);"  required>
     <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
     <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI</option>
     <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC</option>
    </select>
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <label for='IP Address'><strong> IP Address </strong></label>
    <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Left Outlets'><strong>Left Outlets </strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='lo' placeholder='Enter left outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Right Outlets'><strong>Right Outlets</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='ro' placeholder='Enter right outlets' required />
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset>
    <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Chasis Inputs</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='chassis' placeholder='Enter Number of Chasis'  required />
   </fieldset>
   
   <fieldset>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save data to file' />
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Is there any way by which I can apply the same in my existing model. I tried applying on the object but couldn't get it done

Comment: Also, how can i get it in proper sequence. I want the iSCSI IPs to be at that position itself?

Comment: To get it in the same sequence start with empty data controller and then in order check and add properties. You can either do it field by field or add it to the formField array in the order you want and the rest will work fine.

       data[" Controller: # Controller settings \n"] = {};
       if ( !oForm[field.name].disabled ) { 
          // add here
        }